# PHP Mysqli add subtract number format

Tags: php, format, numbers, addition

HI just found a solution about add and sustract two columns here but I need to make the php code to format the numbers.

Here is the solution I got here:

```
<?php
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['money'] - $row['cost'];
}
?>
```

Its working fine for what I need but here is the thing. I use to run the follow php code to all money and numbers

```
<?php echo number_format($product['cost'],0, ",", "."); ?>
```

That way the numbers will display without decimals and like this 100.000

How can I make the code I found here to work with number format?

Something like this I tried but does not work

```
<?php
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo number_format$row['money'] - number_format$row['cost'];
}
?>
```

It must substract and then show the result with formated numbers

Comment: <?php echo number_format($row['money'] - $row['cost'],0, ",", "."); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put it in ()

```
 echo number_format($row['money'] - $row['cost'],0,',','.');
```

More than 2 :

```
echo number_format($row['money'] - $row['cost'] + $row['whatever'] * $row['whatever'],0,',','.');
```

Comment: It worked so nice. Just a small thing. What if I want to add more rows like row1 + row2 + row3 - row4 * row 5 ?

Comment: you can put as much as you want in front of this part : ,0,',','.');